# How to do routing using bootstrap tabs with backbone.js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I've got several tabs built in my index.html like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tabbable">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#new" data-toggle="tab">New Request</a></li>
                <li><a href="#queuepane" data-toggle="tab">Queue</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="appTabs" class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane active"></div>
            <div id="new" class="tab-pane">
            <div id="queue" class="tab-pane"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about having the url change when a tab is clicked using Backbone.js routing?

Comment: Have you read http://backbonejs.org/#Router?

Comment: Have you tried using data-target attributes ??? http://jsfiddle.net/sedhuait/4mxmtn0d/

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using some suggestions I found online. Here's how it looks in coffeescript:

Inside my router's initialize function:

```
$('.tl-navigation-tabs a').click (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @navigate("#{e.target.innerHTML}/", {replace: true, trigger: true})
```

Trigger: true means that if the navigated-to url matches a route in the router, it'll delegate to another function. So here I have a route for each of the tabs, and then inside the function called by going to that route:

```
$(".tl-navigation-tabs a[href='#Events']").tab('show')
```

There's probably a more elegant way to do this, but this ended up working exactly the way I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

Please **use data-target attribute instead of href and

manually change the using Backbone.histroy.navigate('url',false);**

http://jsfiddle.net/sedhuait/4mxmtn0d/

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

```
 <li id="byNumberLi" role="presentation" class=""><a id="byNumberTabLink" data-target="#assignmentByNumberTabConent" data-toggle="tab" role="tab" ><span class="fa fa-list-alt"></span>List
                    By Number</a></li>
```